# Compare dates in Batch File from File Name

Tags: date, batch-file, math, cmd, compare

Need a script that will move files if datetime in filename has passed.

This is what I tried, but its always moving all files.

```
@ECHO OFF
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
SET CurrTime=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b E:\FileLoc\A_ChangePrice_*txt') DO (
    SET "LL=%%G"
    SET CurrFileTime=%LL:~16,-4%
    SET "FileTime=%%CurrFileTime%%"
    CALL ECHO %CurrTime%
    CALL ECHO %FileTime%

    IF %CurrTime% GTR %FileTime% (MOVE E:\FileLoc\%%G CALL ECHO F:\PriceChanges\%%G)
)
```

CurrTime=20150325104003
FileTime=20160425192500

I find 2 problems with this script.

1. the first time script runs FileTime is empty?!
2. It moves file even when FileTime is greater.

There could be a much simpler solution than this, I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Will Set correct answer if you have a cleaner solution.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
SET CurrDateTime=%date:~-2,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%hr%%time:~3,2%

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b E:\FileLoc\A_ChangePrice_*txt') DO (
    SET "FileName=%%G"
    SET /a "FileDateTime=!FileName:~16,-4%!"
    IF %CurrDateTime% GTR !FileDateTime! (CALL MOVE E:\FileLoc\%%G CALL ECHO F:\PriceChanges\%%G)
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: You've discovered `delayedexpansion`, which explains the `file time empty` problem. The other problem is that `gtr` works on a 32-bit signed value, and your values are too large, so the conversion yields incorrect results. You need to force alphabetic comparison (given that the two strings are equal-length) which you can do by including almost any constant alphabetic character before or after the variables, eg `IF q%CurrTime% GTR q!FileTime!...`

Comment: Thank You @Magoo I removed 4 digits from the date so it can fit into a 32-bit signed value. Now the date looks like 1503251233 and it works. Should I still force alphabetic comparison?

Comment: Won't hurt, but there's no advantage either.

Answer (score 0):

Nice resolution to your problem. I tried something similar a while ago, but seeing your code put me on the right path (thanks for that), my reinvention of your code (pretty much the same, except I chose a different method to set the current `datetime`) is below. I tested it using a different `path` and `filename` structure, and it seems to work. Like I said it's pretty much the same but with less expansion modifiers.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (set currdate=%%k%%j%%i)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:. " %%i in ("%time%") do (set currtime=%%i%%j)
set currdt=%currdate:~2%%currtime%

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b C:\XXX\*.txt') do (
    set filename=%%i
    set filedt=!filename:~7%,-4!
    if %currdt% gtr !filedt! (move "C:\XXX\%%i" "C:\YYY\%%i")
)
pause
```